# What is the difference between »neben« vs »bei« vs »am« for location?

Tags: preposition

This is an example from a text:

> Sie trinkt Kaffee am Kamin.

Would there be a difference or would it be wrong to say:

> Sie trinkt Kaffee beim Kamin.
>
> Sie trinkt Kaffee neben dem Kamin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In a nutshell:

There is not much difference in your examples. »Am« and »beim« mean exactly the same in this sentence. »Neben« is almost the same.

»Neben« can not mean »in front of«, only »at the side of«. But »am« and »beim« include both locations.

---

### In Detail

### am

The word »am« is a short form of »an dem«, sometimes also for »an einem«. In southern regions (Austria, Bavaria) is also means »auf dem« (or »auf einem). But since it doesn't make much sense to drink coffee on top of a fireplace, it's clear, that the preposition should be »an«, which is »at« in english. It means, that she is standing next to the fireplace, very close to it. It can be in front of it, or at it's side, but in a short distance. (I would say: The distance is between 0 and 1 meters, maybe also 2 meters. This depends on the size of the room and other circumstances.)

You have no information, if it is a certain fireplace, or just any fireplace, so it's unclear, if the article should be defined (»dem«) or undefined (»einem«). So both versions are possible, depending on the context:

> Sie trinkt Kaffee **an dem** Kamin.
>   She drinks coffee **at the** fireplace.
>
> Sie trinkt Kaffee **an einem** Kamin.
>   She drinks coffee **at a** fireplace.

Without any context, I would think of a certain fireplace, which means »an dem« or in English »at the«.

Note, that »an« is used as a local preposition here, defining a place. But you can use »an« also to define a direction:

> Sie schiebt den Sessel **an den** Kamin.
>   She pushes the chair **to the** fireplace.

When used for a direction, the object has to be in accusative case (*den* Kamin), while it was dative case for the place (*dem* Kamin).

But »an« also can be uses as a temporal preposition:

> Mein Urlaub beginnt **am** Montag. (= ... an dem Montag)
>   My vacation starts **at** Monday.

Note, that when ever »am« meets »dem« you should replace it with »am«. In case of temporal usage, I even would say its wrong to use »an dem«. But technically also in temporal usage »am« is a combination of a preposition and an article.

---

### beim

This again is a short form. It stands for »bei dem« or for »bei einem«. There are no other regional variations. In this sentence it means exactly the same as »am«. (See above.)

But in other sentences they are not interchangeable. »Bei« can be used as a local preposition, but sometimes with other meanings:

> Ich war gestern **bei** Dieter.
>   I visited Dieter yesterday.
>
> Ich war gestern **beim** Bäcker. (= ... bei dem/einem Bäcker)
>   I was **at the** bakery yesterday.

You can not say »Ich war gestern **an** Dieter« or »Ich war gestern **am** Bäcker.« This would be wrong.

> Baden liegt **bei** Wien.
>   Baden is situated **near** Vienna.

Again: »Baden liegt **an** Wien« would be wrong. But this is only true for towns. If something is located at a river, you have to use »an der« or »am« (depending on the river's grammatical gender) (there is no short form for »an der«).

> Wien liegt **an der** Donau.
>   Köln liegt **am** Rhein.
>
> Vienna is situated **on the** Danube.
>   Cologne is situated **on the** Rhine.

»Wien liegt **bei der** Donau« and »Köln liegt **beim** Rhein« are both wrong.

The preposition »bei« has also a temporal usage, if you want to say, that one event happens at the same moment when an other is happening:

> **Beim** Läuten der Glocke waren nur 10 Schüler in der Klasse. (= Bei dem Läuten ...)
>   When the bell rang, only 10 students was in the classroom.

Also this can not be said using »**Am** Läuten ...«.

---

### neben dem

There is no short form for »neben dem«. So here it is clear, that you mean a certain fireplace (not just any fireplace). This is the first difference. So here you can't translate it into English using the article *a*. It must be *the*

The second, more important difference is the location. If she stands in front of the fireplace, you can say »am« or »beim«, but it can't be »neben«, because »neben« means »at the side of«.

> Sie trinkt Kaffee **neben dem** Kamin.
>   She drinks coffee **beside the** fireplace.

I think it's unusual to use »beside« in English, so you normally would translate the sentence as »She drinks coffee next the fireplace«, but in this case you loose the information, that she is not standing or sitting in front of the fireplace. When you say »neben«, then she definitely is located at the side of the fireplace.

»Neben«, as a local preposition, again can mean a place as well as a direction:

place:

> Melania steht **neben** ihrem Mann.
>   Melania is standing **at** her husbands **side**.

direction:

> Er legt den Löffel **neben** das Messer.
>   He puts the spoon **beside** the knife.

»Neben« has no temporal meaning, but can be used as modal preposition:

> **Neben** Klaus haben auch noch Gabi und Anna die Prüfung bestanden.
>   **Apart from** Klaus, also Gabi and Anna passed the exam.

Without further context, in the example above »neben« might also be interpreted as a local preposition: »Sitting next to Klaus, also Gabi and Anna passed the exam.«

The usage of »neben« as modal preposition is rare, and sorry, I couldn't find an example where there is no chance of a misinterpretation.